# Create shape from points / lines in editor and mathematically calculate nearest points within shape

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, algorithm

If I want an editor that accepts "points" of a minimum of three (a triangle) and I just add some points first, like this:

[image]

how can I mathematically connect these corners (points) into an object of multiple triangles? so amount of triangles looks like something like this, by connecting nearest point:

[image]

and then later render this and also being able to define what it is and check for collisions on this ground, so I can create more than Rectangle based "bricks" on a Platformer for example. Also being able to texturize the whole object without it looking ugly.

Any ideas? Or what is this called in game programming?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are describing looks to me like a [triangle strip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_strip). Riemer has a  [tutorial](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series3/Triangle_strip.php)  for creating these in an efficient manner. So if user adds a point you just add one along the bottom of the shape and then create the triangles using the points in a clockwise manner, but the tutorial covers this quite well.

EDIT: 
For collision detection between points you can linearly interpolate between them and check the height value of your object and the interpolated points.

Comment: @Deukalion Did this solve the problem? If not, just leave a comment on what is needed for this to be a solution and I'll see if I can help...