# Creating custom collision map for 2D

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, unity

I have a 2D level that I have built in my map editor, and I was wondering the best way to create a collision map for it.

I have a collision map layer in my map editor, which saves each node (for example, a rectangle would be just 0,0 0,50 50,60 0,60)

I was just wondering how I could take my node locations and convert it to a collision map for Unity.

Thanks!
I feel this has to be able to be done, I can think of how I would do it in flash... but I am not sure how to manipulate it in Unity.

EDIT PICTURE: So I have a node at each one of these red dots (surrounding my terrain lets say)  I want to build a collider from those nodes

[image: nodes collision map]

Comment: I have figured out how to do it in Flash and XNA... is it even possible in UnityPro? (I have basic) but this seems like a fundamental task for creating certain games...

Comment: Check out http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33484/create-shape-from-points-lines-in-editor-and-mathematically-calculate-nearest/33486#33486

Comment: ...and just to be clear, its the part about interpolating between two vertices and checking the height value I think you should check out.

Comment: Thanks Mikael, I suppose I could just roll my own collision, not 100% what I would want, but I think it may be the best solution, see if anyone else has a better idea, if not, I will go with interpolating

Comment: You might get more answers to unity specific questions at [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/index.html).

Comment: @Darcara I have the question posted up there as well... so far nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought since these types of questions seem to show up now and then I'd explain myself a bit more in detail.

Assuming you have a 2D level from a heightmap like in the image without any "overhanging" geometry:

What we want to do is check if point p is below the line, in which case we have a collision at l_p. To accomplish this we interpolate v1.Y and v2.Y value to check the height of the line at p.X. If this l_p.Y is larger than p.Y then there is a collision.

- Start by checking if v1.X <= p.X < v2.X
- calculate interpolation amount (a), ie, how large part of v1.Y and v2.Y respectively should be used where a = (p.X - v1.X) / (v2.X - v1.X)
- calculate interpolated Y by y = (1-a) * v1.Y + a * v2.Y
- if y >= p.Y then there is a collision
- If needed solve interpenetration by setting p.Y = y
- IMPORTANT: If you apply an impulse to the body at this point make sure to check that there is actually a *closing velocity* ie that there is a velocity pointing downwards in this case. Otherwise you might get another collision reported next frame sending the body downwards again.

[image: check if point p is below the line v1-v2]